# Why is type always UIView when I drag and drop UIButton or UILabel to ViewController.swift file

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Below is the screenshot. This is the problem I face when I drag and drop either a `UILabel` or `UIButton`.

[image]

Please help me I am a beginner and I have just started. I just added a button and a label and want to change text in label upon button click but I am facing this problem.

Comment: drag from the left hand side navigator Label instead of from storyboard.

Comment: @sazid008 thanks it worked for me. But is it safe? and why other method is not working?

Comment: It is safest. other mathod not working because you are not dragging correctly

Answer (score 0):

When dragging from the storyboard to the class file to create an `IBOutlet`, if the *containing* view is selected in the navigator (as shown in your screenshot), then that will be linked to the outlet.

To make sure you're connecting to the correct object either

- Select it first by clicking on it, either in the navigator or on the storyboard itself

or

- Drag directly from the navigator

Answer (score -2):

Seems you are trying to create an outlet for **Label Message** View not **Label** that why its always `UIView`

Comment: Didn't understand why I am getting the downvote on this answer.